# ReactJs Bootstrap Validation Error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When i include react-bootstrap-validation v "^0.1.11" i get the following error. 
My page imports like this;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import contactImage from './../images/contact-img.png';
import { Form, ValidatedInput } from 'react-bootstrap-validation';
```

[image: page error looks like this]

If i remove last line, page works correctly. And my package.json looks like this;

```
{
 "name": "coinepo-frontend",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
   "history": "^4.7.2",
   "moment": "^2.20.1",
   "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
   "react": "^16.2.0",
   "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
   "react-bootstrap-validation": "^0.1.11",
   "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
   "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
   "react-router": "^4.2.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
   "redux": "^3.7.2",
   "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 }
}
```

Anyone can help me? 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should downgrade `"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",` to version before `<0.30.0`

Anything under react-bootstrap <0.30.0 works . For example  0.29.5.

For more info, check this [link](https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation/issues/70)

**The reason is**

> If you look at version 0.30.0 of React Bootstrap, there is no component named Input, but in React Bootstrap Validation v0.1.11 for the ValidatedInput component, there is a reference to the Input component, which leads to an error: super expression must be null or a function
>
> https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation/pull/67#issuecomment-235331997

Comment: Thank you for quick response. When i downgrade react-bootstrap version to 0.29.5, i am getting another error. Says;
Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined at PanelGroup.js.
Im trying to fix this problem now.

Comment: i understand the problem. versions are my problem. i will create project again. if i fix this, i will reply. thank you.